# I need to create a KPI in NetSuite. "Items Received Per Week KPI"

Tags: kpi

I need to create  a KPI in NetSuite. "Items Received Per Week KPI", any help? I need this graph and it is not providing a metric to create a graph.

Answer (score 0):

- Use a saved search to get the "Item Received per week"
- source the results of that saved search into a new custom KPI.
- Then you will need a trend graph, below steps are mentioned to set up trend graph portlet

To set up a trend graph portlet:
Click Personalize in the upper right corner of a page or in the Settings portlet.

On the Standard Content tab of the Personalize Dashboard palette, click a Trend Graph icon or drag it onto the dashboard. You can see the number of available trend graph portlets by hovering over the icon.

Click Set Up in the trend graph portlet’s menu.

Select standard or custom KPIs from the KPI dropdown list. You can select a maximum of three KPIs.

Important Custom KPIs are only available in trend graph portlets on pages that include a Key Performance Indicators portlet.
You can also edit the following settings:

In the Custom Portlet Title field, enter a title for the portlet.

Select from the Default Chart Type list to set the default chart type displayed in this portlet.

Chart type options are Area, Line, Bar, and Column.

You can click thumbnails in the portlet itself to dynamically change its chart type from the default set here.

Setting Up Trend Graph Portlets
In addition to the set of four chart type thumbnails on the left, each trend graph portlet includes two thumbnails that you can click to choose either a continuous or side-by-side comparison of data in the trend graph.

If you selected a custom KPI, select a saved search from the Default Trend Type dropdown list. If a saved search is not available, or returns an error when you select it, its definition may not meet requirements for trend graph display. For information, see Displaying Custom KPI Results in Trend Graphs

Select from the Trend Type list to indicate whether the graph's x-axis time scale should be daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly, or yearly. You also can set this option by selecting from a dropdown list in the portlet.

Check the Show Moving Average box to display a dotted line in the trend graph, representing the rolling average of KPI data values. This option is enabled by default.

In the Period to calculate moving average field, enter the number that represents the window of data you want to average based on the date range selected in the Trend Type field. For example, if you select monthly and enter 3 as your window, each data point on your y-axis will represent a 3 month average.

Check the Show Last Data Point box to display the most recent KPI data point in the trend graph. Because the last point may not provide complete data, you may want to exclude this point from the graph to avoid a misleading display. This option is enabled by default.

Check the Include Zero on Y-Axis box to set the first y-axis value for the trend graph to zero, rather than to the initial KPI data point. This option is disabled by default, to avoid showing misleadingly dramatic increases in initial trend graph data.

Select from the Chart Theme dropdown list to set a look and feel for chart data:

Global Theme – uses the chart theme set at Home > Set Preferences (the default). See Personal Preferences for Appearance.

Basic – provides limited color contrast.

Colorful – provides more color contrast.

Match Color Theme - Bold – harmonizes with your choices in the Colors section of the Set Preferences page using bolder shades.

Match Color Theme - Light – harmonizes with your choices in the Colors section of the Set Preferences page using lighter shades.

In the Custom Series Color field, enter a hexadecimal value for a custom color you want to use for the chart. (Note that this option is provided for backwards compatibility with custom chart colors defined prior to the introduction of chart themes in Version 2012 Release 2.)

Select from the Background Type dropdown list to set the display behind chart data:

Global Background – uses the background type set at Home > Set Preferences (the default).

Lines – provides lines that demarcate different levels along the Y-axis.

Bands – provides bands that demarcate different levels along the Y-axis.

Grid – provides a grid all throughout the Y-axis.

When you are done, click Save. The portlet refreshes itself.

Note that each trend graph portlet includes menu options to print the chart, to download it to a PNG, JPG, PDF, or SVG file, and to export its data to a CSV file.

Please let me know how this goes!